# Storing FLOT data in MYSQL in single Data Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, flot

**This Code Works** If you're trying to store a javascript array/object in a single field in a mysql database I've finally figured it out: There is no need for json_ecode/decode functions. No need to load multidimensional arrays in php. Simply use **JSON.stringify.**

```
    <script>
$(function() {
    document.getElementById("send").onclick = function () {
        var amps=[];
        var i = 0;
        while(i<10){
            var rand1 = (Math.round(Math.random()*100))/100;
            var rand2 = (Math.round(Math.random()*100))/100;
            amps.push([rand1, rand2]);
            i = i + 1;
        }
        console.log(amps);
        amps = JSON.stringify(amps);
        var therun = 'data='+amps;
        alert(therun);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "query.php",
            data: therun,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {alert(data);}
        });
    };
});
</script>
```

Then on Query.php

```
<?php

$username="root";
$password="";
$database="amt";

mysql_connect("localhost",$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$encoded = $_POST['data'];

if(isset($_POST['data'])){

$sql="INSERT INTO `amt`.`jsontest` (`id`, `jsonobject`) VALUES (NULL, '".$encoded."');";
$query=mysql_query($sql);

}

?>
```

The final step is to pull it out. No jokes please. ;)

```
<script>
$(function() {
    <?php
    echo "var amps = ".$mysqldata.";\n";
    ?>
        $.plot("#placeholder", [ amps ], {});
});
</script>
```

Hope this is helpful to somebody who is trying to use FLOT like me. :) If you got a more efficient way to do this please let me know.

Comment: You could post this as self-answered question, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: I tried answering my own question, but somebody deleted it. :( The rules on this site are ridiculous.